# Setting client name in NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, httprequest

Hi there,

I'm working with a private API and the guy in charge of the API asked me to change the client name I send to the server when making API calls.

I'm using `NSMutableURLRequest` and for now, I send something like :

> < my app name > iOS App version < version of my app >

But that's automatically set and I don't know how to change it.

Does any of you guys have an idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
[theRequest addValue:@"MyApplication v1.X.X" forHTTPHeaderField:@"MyAppName"];
```

You might also consider using the "User-Agent" header:

```
[theRequest addValue:@"MyApplication v1.X.X" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

Comment: Yes I thought about that, but there will still be this other header I'm talking about right ? I don't know where it is generated

Comment: Check where he creates the session configuration. So look for a call like "[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: @{ }]. Often, default headers are set there so that every call will have them automatically set.